# Google Maps stopped working on WP site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I have a Wordpress site where I embed Google maps into certain pages. They stopped working a couple of weeks ago and I can't figure out what has changed. I don't receive any errors in the Chrome console so its proving difficult to debug. Anyone have any ideas what may have changed on Google's end to make them stop working?

http://blackwoods.com.s110597.gridserver.com/restaurant-locations/duluth-mn/

Cheers

Comment: Did you use a  plugin?

Comment: There is a plugin - but its up-to-date and best I can tell nothing has changed on the repo for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the map type names, for example change G_MAP_TYPE to G_NORMAL_MAP. Check this out http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/upgrade.html#MapTypeNames.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference. I did just notice however that if I resize the window then refresh it will show up in some cases - but the zoom icons are always blurred out regardless. So is it possible there is conflicting js/css somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... I had added a css declaration that was overly broad in targeting. I had a class like so:

```
#wrapper{max-width: 100%}
```

So the GMap imagery and icons were getting scaled inappropriately. To correct I simply targeted my GMap container div and added:

```
#wrapper .GMaps{max-width: none !important}
```

And that seems to have corrected the issues. Thank you for your help guys.